# How to open a default file in a Visual Studio Code devcontainer

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote, vscode-tasks, github-codespaces

I have a few devcontainer configurations that I use with both the Visual Studio Code Remote Container extensions and GitHub Codespaces to teach classroom topics.

I have a sample here on GitHub: https://github.com/seesharprun/how-to-sql-query

I want to figure out how to open a file and the Markdown preview on launch when someone opens this project in a devcontainer (either using Code or Codespaces).

VSCode.dev seems to do this already: https://open.vscode.dev/seesharprun/how-to-sql-query

This would allow me to open something like a default *.cs file or the preview of a readme.md file with instructions on how to complete the "lab" for students.

I have looked at https://containers.dev/ to learn more about the JSON schema definition. I have seen things like the `postCreateCommand`, `postAttachCommand` and the `postStartCommand`. I tried using the command `code readme.md --reuse-window` with `postAttachCommand`, but that didn't seem to work. I also looked at `tasks` but couldn't find anything to help there either.

Answer (score 3):

Per [Jonathan Carter on Twitter](https://twitter.com/LostInTangent/status/1601312261242753025), there's a `customizations.codespaces.openFiles` property that takes an array of files to open on launch. Here's a link to the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/codespaces/setting-up-your-project-for-codespaces/automatically-opening-files-in-the-codespaces-for-a-repository).

The property allows you to open the files in their default editor. It doesn't quite allow you to open the Markdown file as a preview (like VSCode.dev) but it solved my problem.